# Use tensorflow.js model in android

Tags: android, tensorflow, mobile, tensorflow-lite

There are some great models in tensorflow.js for face mesh detection, pose detection etc. How can I use these models on Android? Is there a way to convert tensorflow.js models to tflite models?

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting your tf.js model into Keras python model first (refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter), and then convert it to a lite model (refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert).

Or you can run your model directly in a node.js server with no need to conversion, and then use the server as a backed server to your android app.

Comment: It seems like not all tfjs models are convertible to keras .. at least not by the above method. I tried the above approach with face-mesh model and it failed.

Comment: Can you please share the code and the error that you got ?